# how to install NS2.35 in M1 macbook as an error is 404 is displayed and unable to locate packages

Tags: boot, ns2

running Ubuntu on M1 Parallels. trying to install NS2.35 on ubuntu version 20.04. unable to do so due to an error stating unable to locate ARM64 files along with error 404. any suggestions on how to get this done??

Comment: It's almost impossible to diagnose an error when you don't explain the context and you don't tell us the actual error.  Please edit your question with actionable details. You should provide the entire context of all steps and commands that you have done to reproduce the error. Then give the entire error, verbatim and unredacted.  If the software is not in Ubuntu repos you should also explain how you obtained the software and all steps you have taken in attempts to install this software.

Comment: NS2 is in the Ubuntu repositories. A 404 error suggests that something is wrong with your apt sources. Without real output, you're asking us to speculate beyond that.

Comment: Please add more details. NS2 is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ns2). Start with `sudo apt-add-repository universe; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install ns2` .